# adding class object to array overwrites all array items - VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, object

I am trying to store a class object in an array. I have created the example below for my problem to make it simple.

I want to add an object of a class to an array in a loop. The object is changed at each loop pass and then added to the array. The problem is that with each loop pass the previous objects in the array are overwritten.

```vbnet
 Public Class Itemproperties
        Public Number As String
        Public Hight As Single
End Class
Public ItemStorage(6) As Itemproperties
Public Item As New Itemproperties

Private Sub ClassObjectToArray(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To ItemStorage.Length - 1
            Item.Hight = i + 1
            ItemStorage(i) = Item

            Console.WriteLine(ItemStorage(0).Hight)
        Next
    End Sub
```

The output should be `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` but is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.
It seems that it is not the object that is added to the array, but rather a pointer to the object.

If I try the same system on a very simple example with an integer, it works without problems:

```vbnet
Dim x As Integer
Dim testarray(6) As Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To testarray.Length - 1
    x = i + 1
    testarray(i) = x
    Console.WriteLine(testarray(0))
Next
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

###### Edit:

I have tried out whether I have initialised the array or the individual elements incorrectly. If I break down the class and add it individually to the array it works, but then I have to initialise each element beforehand with `testarray(i) = New Itemproperties`.

```vbnet
Item.Hight = i + 1
ItemStorage(i) = New Itemproperties
ItemStorage(i).Hight = Item.Hight
```

If I remove the breakdown but still initialise each element, unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: You're only creating one object and adding it over and over. You need to create multiple objects, one each time you want to add one.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I only have one object that I keep adding, but I change it every time I run it and store it in the array. The stored objects shouldn't change, should they?
If I break down the object, I can do it without creating new objects from Item.

Comment: I tried it out, as you said, if I reinitialise the object/create a new one with each loop pass, i.e. `Item = New Itemproperties`, then I get the correct output. But then I have dozens of objects that I don't need any more and unfortunately I don't know how to access them again.
In my simple example with an integer variable, I don't have to create a new object for each loop, right?

Comment: `Integer` is a value type - a structure - while classes are reference types. You should do some research on the difference. It's critical that .NET developers understand the difference.

Comment: Consider this. Let's say that you are creating a list of people. I present myself to you wearing a red shirt and you add my name to the list. I then present myself to you again wearing a green shirt and you put my name on the list. I then present myself to you a third time wearing a blue short and you put my name on the list. If you then call all the names on your list and I present myself to you each time you call my name, would you be surprised that I had a blue shirt on all three times? Of course you wouldn't. I'm one person added to the list three times. That's what you're doing here.

Comment: Of course you still need the objects. What are you creating any objects for if you don't need them? When you have an egg carton, do you add one egg to it a dozen times or do you add a dozen eggs to it? As for how you access them, of course you know. You showed it in your code. You access an array element by indexing the array. If you add them properly in the first place, you'll get them back properly.

Comment: Yes, to add a new copy of the object to the array, then yes, you have to use the New keyword each time.  -- see my post below.

Comment: There ought to be a canonical dupe target for reference vs value type.  I think I recall writing an answer about the difference in the past, not sure if it was as detailed as the one Albert wrote below.  Relatedly, this question is almost certainly a duplicate, but I didn't get an obvious hit for a target when I hit the flag button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a great question!

Joel on Software once noted that a class full of people having learned some programming language and then hit the part about "pointers" in the class. That's when the class drops from 70 enrolled down to less then 30!!!

The simple way to explain this?

When you use a variable like integer or string?

They ARE a variable and they are referenced by "value".

However, when you create/use an object? Your variable is ONLY a pointer to the actual object!!!

So, say this code:

```
Public Class Itemproperties
    Public Number As String
    Public Hight As Single
End Class
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim a As New Itemproperties

    Dim b As Itemproperties = a
    Dim c As Itemproperties = a

    a.Hight = 5000

    Debug.Print($"b height = {b.Hight}")
    Debug.Print($"c height = {c.Hight}")


End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

So, a, b, and c are ALL THE SAME variable!!!!

So, your variable is in fact a pointer to the ONE object. A nice way to think of this is when you pass values to a sub routine. Are you using By Val (a new value (copy) is passed, and thus changes in the sub don't travel back to the caller routine).

Or, are you using By Ref (by reference, a pointer!). When you use By Ref, you are NOT passing a copy of the variable to the sub routine, but in fact are passing a reference (pointer).

Hence a copy of the variable is not made, and any changes in the sub to that passed value will be returned.

So, in your case?

You are creating ONE instance of the class, and sending it over and over to the array. The result is the array is JUST holding a list of pointers to the ONE class, and each element in the array points to the ONE instance of that class. (just like b and c in the above).

The simple solution to the above is to ensure that you create a new instance of the class each time, and then shove that into your array.

Hence, like this:

```
    Dim MyProps(10) As Itemproperties

    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim MyItem As New Itemproperties
        MyItem.Hight = 1000 * i
        MyProps(i) = MyItem
    Next

    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print($"height for index {i} = {MyProps(i).Hight}")
    Next
```

Output:

[image]

So, just remember that "objects" in a variable are not in fact the object, but ONLY a pointer (reference) to the real object in memory.

So, create a new instance each time, and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for this super detailed answer. I already had a premonition that I was putting pointers into the array but didn't realise that classes are generally handled as reference types. Learned something new again.

Comment: But I still have one question: I can then access the newly created objects again via the array. But what happens if I go one step further and overwrite the array elements because I run the loop over them again, for example? The references to the objects are then gone, but the objects still exist, right?

Comment: They are garbage collected. And of course like all variables in that routine they go out of scope when you exit the sub. As to when GC occurs is complex subject,  hence in many cases a using block is recommended,  but I can't say that applies to an array.  I rarely use arrays and near always use collections anyway - They tend to be for/each friendly and they have add/remove methods.

Comment: In the original project, I don't have this structure and the variables in a separate subroutine, but in a larger infinite loop. However, I took a look at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-lifetime-how-objects-are-created-and-destroyed) and if the reference is removed, it ends up in the trash, as you said, so it shouldn't be a problem, hopefully.

Comment: I use an array in my use case because I need a fixed number of elements and this is not possible with a list.
I can't yet imagine how I should use the Using block, do you mean like this, for example: `Using MyItem As New Itemproperties`

Comment: @Newt `Using` / `Dispose` only has an effect on non-memory resources (and one should always be aware of it and handle it when it's necessary i.e. any time working with types that implement `IDisposable`).  The memory will be collected during GC regardless of whether `Dispose` is used.

Comment: I would not worry and introduce "using" for a array or collection (as I pointed out already).  So, you are just fine. As for the fixed number? Not really relevant, since over time such things may well change. I just like collections over arrays since they can grow, and have great ease to add or remove elements etc.